# Core package not found, when building liblinphone 4.0.0 for Android

Tags: linphone, linphone-sdk

Before LibLinphone 4.0.0 SDK for Android was out, I was using some random old library of linphone-sdk.aar which I found in some project. Size of .aar is around 15mb and this library works ok and I have options to include files from

```
org.linphone.tools
org.linphone.core
org.linphone.mediastream
```

Now I tried to download and update Linphone with

```
liblinphone-android-sdk.4.0.0.zip
```

from  http://www.linphone.org/technical-corner/liblinphone/downloads

I removed older .aar, and included this one which is present in this zip file, but my project returns errors, because it cannot find package

```
org.linphone.core
```

Other 2 packages tools/mediastream are found normally as before.

**-** Then I tried to build linphone-android from the source files, and after alot of problems I got .aar version, but the problem is the same!

**-** Then I saw you can download some snapshots of builds from linphone on
https://www.linphone.org/snapshots/android/
and found version

```
liblinphone-android-sdk-3.3.2-54-g115f74d
```

This version works normally, but the size of .aar is around 80mb!

**Questions regarding this problems**

1. Does anyone know why this 4.0.0 SDK version has problems
2. Do I have to build something else from source files (I was using **make liblinphone-android-sdk**) for this to work?
3. Why are some .aar files so different in sizes, does this with 80mb have anymore included than the one that is only 15mb? Which size for latest liblinphone is ok?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue...

In 4.0+(probably) they renamed all files which have **Linphone** in the name, for example

**LinphoneCore**  -> ***Core***

also they renamed all Interfaces used, for example

**LinphoneAccountCreator.RequestStatus** -> ***Status*** (This is replaced with only Status interface, which is included into multiple classes like Call, AccountCreator,.. in this case this is present in AccountCreator class)

and also enum types like callDirection and even function names

**call.getDirection() == CallDirection.Incoming** -> ***call.getDir() == Call.Dir.Incoming***

Comment: I'm using LinphoneSDK 4.0.1 ... after the call establish, I can't hear anything .... any idea what's the problem & how to fix it?

Comment: @SolaimanHossain hard to say... 
I would first try linphone app to is if it is working, then you can try to change some codecs or some settings in app and if linphone app is working then try to find some problem or difference in Android sample from their github and your code

Answer (score 0):

about the size question i don't know if 80mb means more features will test that version,

however the latest 4.0.0 ( 4.0.1 is out but they did not update the link yet , i don't know why) has lots of code reformatting and  class renaming i don't know if any bugs were fixed but possible

if you need a clear example of usage , you should check linphone android git hub [here](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android)

the most important class is the preference [here](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android/blob/master/src/android/org/linphone/LinphonePreferences.java)
and the linphone manger also [here](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android/blob/master/src/android/org/linphone/LinphoneManager.java)

Answer (score 0):

According to lead Belladonne developer, they've abandoned the Java wrapper in place of an automated one: https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android/issues/484#issuecomment-466419232

I'm in the middle of trying to build 4.1 with the old wrapper (according to this developer's advice). So far it fails hard: https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android/issues/486

While trying to port the code to the new API (as per @Tomek's advice) I've found a lot of needed changes, so this remains PLAB B.